# SDN OGM @Properties for Map of Collections

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I use Spring Data Neo4j OGM version.

I need to dynamically be able to store the following:

```
@Properties(prefix = "replaceableSkillIds", allowCast = true)
private Map<String, Set<Long>> replaceableSkillIds;
```

but right now the application fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Could not map key=replaceableSkillIds.1, value=[6, 3, 9, 8] (type = class java.util.ImmutableCollections$SetN) because it is not a supported type.
```

Is there something I may do in order to achieve this?

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/955 is solved and will be part of future (mind the comment's post date) releases.